# Quotes generating html entity

Tags: c#

I'm trying to replace a bunch of consecutive

```
var: $("#var").val()
```

lines in my JS script with a simple loop in c# like this:

```
@foreach(var q in myList){
    @(q.var + ": $('#" + q.var + "').val()," + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

But any symbol I try to pass (', \" or "") generates the html entity (&-#39; or &-quot;).

```
var: $(&quot;#var&quot;).val()
```

and JS errors.

With a view only solution, is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Are you working with Razor? Try to use Html.Raw

Comment: Yes. Same effect. @(q.var + Html.Raw(": $(\"#") + q.var + Html.Raw("\").val(),") + Environment.NewLine);

Comment: Nevermind that... Chrome F12 tools were not updating the source code correctly... Html.Raw works fine...

Comment: @Haitam If you post your answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Done, I used your working line of code if that's no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have an official answer in this post (or for futur readers) I will put my comment as an answer, which seems to have resolved the issue.

What you should use is `Html.Raw` to print raw content.

```
@(q.var + Html.Raw(": $(\"#") + q.var + Html.Raw("\").val(),") + Environment.NewLine);
```